# Play Framework - Pagination using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

It seems to be the following syntax didn't work. Do we have any alternate query for this?

```
JPA.em().createQuery(queryStr).getResultList().from(startAt).fetch(offset);
```

As we know, from() and fetch() will work only on JPAQueryobject and the above code will produce List instead of JPAQueryobject.

Please note that queryStr combines 2 different models.

Is there anyway to get JPAQueryobject from the above query? So that I can use from and fetch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could you be a little more precise about the "didn't work" part? Do you have any error, or something like that?

On my application, I implemented some pagination features, and an example of the JPA query is this one (`News` is one model of my application):

```
public static void news(int size, int page) {
    // 'size' is the number of elements displayed per page
    // 'page' is the current page index, starting from 1.
    int start = page * size;
    List<News> allNews = News.find("order by date desc").from(start).fetch(size);
    // Once the list of news is found, we return them in Json format...
    renderJSON(allNews, new NewsJsonSerializer());
}
```

---

Regarding your edit: The method `createQuery` returns a [`Query`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/Query.html) object. Thus, you can use `setFirstResult()` method and `setMaxResults()` instead of `from()` and `fetch()`. Applied on your code, your query now looks like:

```
JPA.em().createQuery(queryStr).setFirstResult(startAt).setMaxResults(offset).getResultList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. I have edited the question and it's more clear now.

Comment: @Siva I've edited my post to give you another example of code, which is closer to your suggestion. I think it is what you are looking for...